# SQL Server Report Builder Row Group Only Showing First Record

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The values I have in the row group are not First, Sum or anything else that would summarize a row.  All records should be returned as simply the Fields!FieldName.Value of the dataset.  Consider the following dataset:

```
 SerlNmbr     ItemNmbr    Qty 
 ABC123       34562334     2
 ABC123       23314454     1
 ABC123       09878976     3
```

So if in my table I set up row group "Serial" to group by field SerlNmbr to display the ItemNmbr and Qty, I should see:

```
SerlNmbr     ItemNmbr     Qty
ABC123 
             34562334      2
             23314454      1
             09878976      3
```

But instead, I only get the first row of the dataset.  But then when I go back in the Serial group and take out the grouping by SerlNmbr, I get:

```
SerlNmbr    ItemNmbr      Qty
ABC123
            34562334       2
ABC123 
            23314454       1
ABC123
            09878976       3
```

So I know that my dataset is returning all 3 rows.  Why is my grouping removing all but the first?

Comment: I can actually make the third grouping example work IF, I can not only hide duplicate values, but hide the blank row as well.  I know I can go into the row properties and set HideDuplicates = SerlNmbr, but it still returns a blank row where SerlNmbr would've been.  How do I make it stop returning the row?

Comment: Got it.  =IIF(Previous(Fields!SerlNmbr.Value) = Fields!SerlNmbr.Value, True, False) in the SerlNmbr row visibility.  I'm good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it may not be the most proper way, but I got what I needed by leaving it grouped the way it is in my third example and simply hiding the SerlNmbr rows that are duplicates by doing

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!SerlNmbr.Value) = Fields!SerlNmbr.Value, True, False)
```

in row visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this on a similiar database schema.  My advice is to recreate the report and ensure that the fields `ItemNmbr` and `Qty` are in the details section of the report.  Highlight this row, and add a new group item.  Add in `SerlNmbr` as the field to group on.  Ensure the fields in your details section say Fields!ItemNmbr.Value and not `FIRST(...)`.

Add a group footer and header.  In the footer add the following:

`=Count(Fields!ItemNmbr.Value)`

See if it returns the number of sub items for a serial number.